# Error: Plugin "@typescript-eslint" was conflicted between ".eslintrc.js » plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-type-check

Tags: vue.js, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

Error: Plugin "@typescript-eslint" was conflicted between ".eslintrc.js » plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-type-checked » ./configs/base" and ".eslintrc.js » @vue/eslint-config-typescript/recommended » plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended » ./configs/base".

```
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true,
    es6: true
  },
  parser: 'vue-eslint-parser',
  plugins: ['standard-recommended'],
  
  extends: [
    'plugin:vue/vue3-essential',
    'plugin:vue/vue3-strongly-recommended',
    'plugin:vue/vue3-recommended',
    'eslint:recommended',
    '@vue/eslint-config-typescript/recommended',
    '@vue/eslint-config-prettier',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-type-checked',
    './.eslintrc-auto-import.json'
  ],
  
  parserOptions: {
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    ecmaVersion: 'latest',
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true
    }
  },
 
  noInlineConfig: true,
  reportUnusedDisableDirectives: true,
  ignorePatterns: [
    '*.sh',
    'node_modules',
    '*.md',
    '*.woff',
    '*.ttf',
    '.vscode',
    '.idea',
    'dist',
    '/docs',
    '.husky',
    '.github'
  ],
}
```

```
{
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.dom.json",
  "include": ["env.d.ts", "src/**/*", "src/**/*.vue", "auto-imports.d.ts", "components.d.ts"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    // TODO delete
    "ignoreDeprecations": "5.0",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "paths": {
      // TODO: delete https://github.com/userquin/unocss-browser-issue
      "@unocss/preset-icons/browser": ["./node_modules/@unocss/preset-icons/dist/browser"],
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
      "@c/*": ["./src/components/*"],
      "@v/*": ["./src/views/*"]
    },
    "lib": ["ESNext", "DOM"],
    "types": ["vite/client", "naive-ui/volar"]
  }
}
```

Comment: your issue is going to be that you have multiple versions of the packages installed and they're referenced by different configs. so eslint is telling you "hey you have 2 versions of this plugin being required at the same time - which is a big probem". you need to fix this by ensuring your workspace only contains one version of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

[Back up your project and] delete the `.lock` file generated by your package manager and reinstall the dependencies.

#### Lock file generated:

- **NPM**: `package-lock.json`
- **Yarn**: `yarn.lock`
- **PNPM**: `pnpm-lock.yaml`

#### Reinstall dependencies:

1. Delete `node_modules`
2. Install dependencies

```
npm install # for npm
yarn install # for yarn
pnpm install # for pnpm
```